# One root of $x^2 + px + q = 0$, for $p, q$ real, is $x = 2 + 3i$. How do you find $p$ and $q$?

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, quadratics

One root of $x^2 + px + q = 0$, for $p, q$ real, is $x = 2 + 3i$. How do you find $p$ and $q$?

What I have tried so far:

$(2+3i)(2-3i)$

$=4-6i+6i-9i^2$

$=4+9 = 13$

Therefore $q$ is $13$

But I don't know how to find the value of $p$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $p = -((2 + 3i) + (2 - 3i)) = -4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots, then we have

$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0$

$$x^2-(\alpha+\beta) x+\alpha \beta = 0$$

Since your equation is monic,

$$p=-(2+3i+2-3i)=-4$$

Answer (score 0):

$p$ and $q$ are not unique as the same polynomial multiplied by any nonzero constant has the same roots. Other than that Siong Thye Goh showed how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The roots must occur in conjugate pairs (why?), so the polynomial must actually be
$$(x-2-3i)(x-2+3i)$$
$$=x^2 -4x +13$$

because $(x-z)(x-\bar{z}) = x^2 -2 \operatorname{Re} z +|z|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

This argument starts from less information.  Suppose we didn't *know* that the "other root" of the quadratic equation (call it $ \ r \ $ ) is the complex conjugate of $ \ 2 + 3i \ \ , $ but we wish the coefficients $ \ p \ $ and $ \ q \ $ to be real numbers.  The polynomial would factor as $ \ ( x - 2 - 3i ) · ( x - r )  \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ giving us
$$ x^2 \ + \ px \ + \ q \ \ = \ \ x^2 \ - \ (2 + 3i + r)·x \ + \ (2 + 3i)·r \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ .  $$
We see from this that $ \ r \ $ *cannot* simply be a real number because both $ \ p \ = \ -(2 + 3i + r) \ $ and $ \ q \ = \ (2 + 3i)·r \ $ would be left with imaginary parts.

We can *make* $ \ p \ $ a real number by choosing $ \ r \ = \ a - 3i \ \ , $ so that $ \ p \ $ becomes equal to $ \ -(2 + a) \ \ . $  As for the other coefficient,   we find $ \ q \ = \ (2 + 3i)·(a - 3i) \ = \ (2a + 9) \ + \ (3a - 6)·i \ \ . $  We can make *this* a real number by setting $ \ 3a - 6 \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ a \ = \ 2 \ \ . $  From this, we have $$  r \ = \ 2 - 3i \ \ , \ \ p \ = \ -(2 + 2) \ = \ -4 \ \ , \ \ q \ = \ (2·2 + 9) \ + \ 0·i \ = \ 13 \ \ , $$ and the quadratic equation, $ \ x^2 - 4x + 13 \ = \ 0 \ \ . $